# DL180 G6 server suddenly loses access to SSD datastore on ESXi 6.0

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant

I've currently got a HP ProLiant DL180 G6 server. It originally came with a Smart Array P410i raid card, which I used to create a bunch of RAID0 disks (one SSD for my ESXi datastore and a couple of HDDs for my FreeNAS virtual machine). All the disks were connected to the raid card through the server's backplane, and everything seemed to work perfectly back then.

Some months later, as I read that it is common knowledge that you shouldn't run FreeNAS with a raid card, I decided to buy a HPE H220 Host Bus Adapter which I would configure to work in IT mode. Then, I connected the HDDs which would be pass through to the FreeNAS VM to the HBA (through the backplane) and the SSD to one of the SATA ports on the server's mainboard.

In order to provide power to the SSD, I use a SATA power to 4 pin floppy adapter to connect my SSD to the only spare cable that comes out of the power supply (which bears the word "CD"), as you can see in the following pictures:
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAJ2V.jpg)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em8oT.jpg)

However, although the SSD seems to work, when put under heavy load, it suddenly disconnects and my ESXi instance reports errors such as "Lost access to volume" and "All paths down". As a consequence, all my VMs crash as they are located on the datastore hosted on the SSD, and I need to reboot the whole machine.

I supect that the issue is caused by the SSD not receiving enough power from the CD cable that comes out of the PSU. If that is so, then how can I correctly provide power to my SSD?

Answer (score 1):

This is all a bad idea ;)

You're better off going back to the original configuration or changing the SSD setup.

For the SSD, please either use a real drive bay connected to the backplane or use a PCIe or NVMe connection.

Edit:
You can mount your existing SSD to a PCIe adapter.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is a bad idea? Anyway, I can neither go back to the original configuration, because using a raid card is **highly** discouraged with FreeNAS, nor attach the SSD to the backplace, because I have to passthrough the HBA to the FreeNAS VM and I would still need a drive for my ESXi datastore. Considering this scenario, would ditching the current SSD and buying a new PCIe/NVMe drive the only solution then?

Comment: Would you mind recommending me an adapter for my Samsung 860 Pro SSD?